# iOS entitlements where is it stored inside the .app

Tags: ios, codesign, entitlements, .app, code-signing-entitlements

I have an iOS app and I couldn't find entitlements.plist or somethig inside the app but I can find info.plist and the contents of entitlements are not there too.

when I run the below command in terminal I am getting the entitlements.

```
codesign -d --entitlements - test.app
```

so Where is it stored ?

Its definitely not stored in info.plist I checked it out.

Help me understand where is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's in a different file- projectName.entitlements

Comment: Ok but I am unable to find it inside the .app

Comment: Oh, you are asking about the .app, didn't notice that. The entitlements will be embedded in the signature of an application, and also embedded in the app bundle as Example.app.xcent. There are some useful guides if you want to check the entitlements.

Comment: I uncompressed my .ipa I couldn't find .app.xcent and I opened code signature I couldn't find there too... for example my entitlements has applicaiton identitifer,team identitifer etc... but I sofar I coulnd't find where it draws from

Comment: The way to see the entitlements is the way you did it, using codesign -d. What do you try to achieve? check that you have all the entitlements you wanted? or maybe to understand why you have those entitlements?

Comment: I just want to know where the details are coming from !

Comment: check the entitlements you have in the project's capabilities tab and at the app developer page

Comment: Yeah , That I understand but in the .app where it is stored I couldn't find that.

Comment: It's probably not within a file so you wan't be able to edit it

Comment: Ok ! I get it.But where `codesign -d --entitlements` gets the entitlement from ?

Comment: I don't think its there because I removed signature file,info.plist,embedded.mobileprovision from there and it still gives the entitlement

Answer (score 0):

Inside embedded.mobileprobision under the 'Entitlements' key.

In addition, The Mach-O executable (stored inside the IPA archive) may have an embedded copy of the entitlements dictionary.

p.s. [Apple's Technical Note TN2415](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2415/_index.html) specify: "When a profile is used for code signing, Xcode transfers the profile's associated entitlements to the resulting code signature of the .app".